# How can I access a specific variable from laravel 6.x to vuejs (i try implement mouseover dynamically)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-6

i need access to a especific object from my array, this array comes from my controller.

```
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="(aesp ,index) in aespNew" :key="aesp.id" :data-id="aesp.id">
                <div v-if="aesp.lang == 0">
                    <button type="button"
                    v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: aesp.color, color: texColor, borderColor: aesp.color }"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    @mouseover="mouseOver()"
                    @mouseout="mouseOut()"
                    :data-id="aesp.area_id"
                    >{{ aesp.areaEs }} <span><b>{{ aesp.id }}</b></span>
                    </button>
                    <br>
                </div>
        </div>
```

and I need access to `aesp.color` in my function mouseOver

```
 mouseOver: function(){
 
  console.log(this.aespNew);
  this.bgColor = 'yellow'; //<-- the aesp.color hear, but i cant for now, why?
 
       },
```

and this `console.log(this.aespNew);` print

[image]

this function when i hover any item of buttons, the items hover too with the same color of button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see from your code that `aespNew` is an array you loop over `v-for="(aesp ,index) in aespNew"`. So yeah it is expected that you receive all the items of that array. What you are looking for is passing the `aesp` to you `mouseOver` callback.

```
@mouseover="mouseOver(aesp)"

mouseOver: function(aesp) {
    this.bgColor = aesp.color;
},
```

A good example can be found in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers).